# IsMouseOver trigger for DockPanel not firing unless children are hovered over

Tags: wpf, dockpanel

This question has been asked a couple of times before, but at this time, none of the answers I've found turned out to be working.

So I have a custom `DockPanel` with 2 child elements inside, 1 `TextBox` and 1 `Image`. 
I intended to have the DockPanel change color on hover, so I put a Trigger inside of it. But currently, it only changes color if I hover over the children, whereas a hover over whitespace between elements doesn't do anything.

I've read similar posts which mentioned using `isHitTestVisible`, but it doesn't do anything.

Short version of my code is the following:

```
<DockPanel>

    <!-- Change color on mouse hover -->
    <DockPanel.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                 <Trigger Property="DockPanel.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                       <Setter Property="DockPanel.Background" Value="#FFe6ffe6"/>
                 </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DockPanel.Style>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DockPanel.Dock="Center">
        <!-- TextBox and Image code here -->
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your dock panel style.

```
<Trigger Property="DockPanel.IsMouseOver" Value="False">
      <Setter Property="DockPanel.Background" Value="Transparent"/>
</Trigger>
```